# Why does NIST SP 800 `KDF in Counter Mode' specification require a PRF rather than a PRP?

Tags: key-derivation

This is the [NIST SP 800](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-108.pdf) KDF in Counter Mode specification.

[image: KDF in Counter Mode]

Where $K_I$ is the input key, $[i]_2$ is the counter value, Label and Context are fixed-length strings and $[L]_2$ is the output size, the input to the PRF for each block $i\in n$ is as follows

$$K(i) := \operatorname{PRF} (K_I, [i]_2 \mathbin\Vert \mathit{Label} \mathbin\Vert \mathrm{0x00} \mathbin\Vert \mathit{Context} \mathbin\Vert [L]_2)$$

I'm trying to understand why

> this Recommendation approves the use of either the keyed-hash Message Authentication Code (HMAC) specified in [[8]](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.198-1.pdf) or the cipher-based Message Authentication Code (CMAC) specified in [[7]](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-38b.pdf) as the pseudorandom function.

Why not just use a straightforward PRP like AES here? Provided the fixed input data is of the correct width, I don't see why the complexity of using i.e. a CMAC PRF is being added to the construction.

Moreover, looking at the NIST CMAC specification and adapting it for one-block fixed-length inputs it seems the only difference would be XORing a second key with the input to the PRP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic goal—not really explicated by the standard—of these KDF constructions is to turn an unstructured-input short-output PRF $f$ into a structured-input long-output PRF $\operatorname{KDF-}\!f$, whose PRF-advantage has some standard reduction to the PRF-advantage of $f$.

If the label, context, counter, *etc.*, are all short enough, you could instantiate it with a PRP instead of a PRF for $f$, and you would incur the [standard PRP-for-PRF cost on security bounds](https://cr.yp.to/papers.html#permutations).  It is likely that with CMAC, you don't pay that cost—though I haven't done the analysis to be sure.

Comment: I don't know where that HKDF suddenly came from; to my opinion it is obscuring the question - it certainly isn't present in the answer. Could you clarify that part?

Comment: I was reading and writing too fast and I forgot which choice of KDF the question was asking about by the time I got to that word.  Fixed!